# Percent groovy list slicing

Tags: groovy, sublist

my code:

```
def originalList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]

def newList = orginalList.percent(0.05,0.95) //I have no idea what I'm doing here
println newList
```

I have an original list of numbers, they are 1 - 100 and i want to make a new list from the original list however the new list must only have data that belongs to the sub-range 5%- 95% of the original list

so the new list must be like `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18....95]`. How do i do that? i know my newList code is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like:

```
originalList[ 4..94 ] // zero starting pos
```

Or do you need percentages?

You could do:

```
originalList[ (originalList.size() * 0.05 - 1)..<(originalList.size() * 0.95) ]
```

You could also use the metaClass:

```
List.metaClass.percent { double lower, double upper ->
    int d = lower * delegate.size() - 1
    int t = upper * delegate.size()
    delegate.take( t ).drop( d )
}

originalList.percent( 0.05, 0.95 )
```