# groovy : split list into sub-lists equi-size

Tags: list, groovy

if i have :

```
def all=[11,12,12,13,13,13,14,15,16,10]
```

i want to split this list into 3 sublists that has almost the same size .

```
def result=[[11,12,12],[13,13,13],[14,15,16,10]]
```

i add a method to metaClass of List class : it is `percent` metod:

See : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20005844/747579

So i can do :

```
def result=[all.percent(0,0.33),all.percent(0.34,0.66),all.percent(0.67,1)]
```

My question is : There is a method that splits a list into n sub-lists equisize , such as ;

```
 def result=all.equisize(n) // n is the number of sublist wanted
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try:

```
def result = all.collate( all.size().intdiv( 3 ) )
```

Which gives:

```
assert result == [ [ 11, 12, 12 ], [ 13, 13, 13 ], [ 14, 15, 16 ], [ 10 ] ]
```

If you don't want to keep the spare `[10]` at the end, you could pass `false` to the `keepRemainder` parameter of `collate`:

```
def result = all.collate( all.size().intdiv( 3 ), false )
```